# Technical problem with trying to unstake EOS so it can be withdrawn to an exchange etc

Tags: net, unstake

As I understand it, in order to transfer/withdraw/exchange EOS, it must first be unstaked, after which it is held for 3 days temporarily in the 'net' status column, and is then automatically transferred to the EOS category.

If the way this is supposed to work, then can someone please explain why after I undelegated some EOS several weeks ago, it is still sitting in the "net" field and never moved automatically to the EOS field after 3 days had passed? Is there another step I have to make to make it transfer if it doesn't happen automatically? It has been stuck in the "NET" (3 day pending) category for something like 2 or 3 months now. Is there also a reason why this process must be done via eostoolkit.io and cannot simply be done via scatter?

Oh and I tried the refund fallback option as well, and got a failure message with this data...

> { "code": 500, "message": "Internal Service Error", "error": { "code":
>   3050003, "name": "eosio_assert_message_exception", "what":
>   "eosio_assert_message assertion failure", "details": [ { "message":
>   "assertion failure with message: refund request not found", "file":
>   "wasm_interface.cpp", "line_number": 924, "method": "eosio_assert" },
>   { "message": "pending console output: ", "file": "apply_context.cpp",
>   "line_number": 72, "method": "exec_one" } ] } }

Thank You

p.s It is wonderful that you allow people to post without having to open an account, thus removing one of the most irritating, exasperating, and oppressive barriers to free and open discussion on the internet. This feels like the exact kind of spirit we should have around open blockchain projects. Well done!

Comment: Hi Lex, can you send me your eosio account name so i can check the exact problem for you?

Comment: Hi, it is gy4dcmrrhage

Thanks

Comment: gy4dcmrrhage, i checked your account both currently ledger and refund table don't have any record of you undelegating the bandwith. Make sure you have properly undelegate bw, your EOS will be refunded after 3 days through deferred transaction.

https://eosq.app/search?q=action%253Aundelegatebw%2520auth%253Agy4dcmrrhage

Make sure you use the proper tool to undelegate bandwidth. 

EOSIO cannot give free account to users because it can lead to spamming and can jam the whole network and it's resources. b1 currently working on SSI to solve this problem and provide other features.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding was that funds that are in the 3 day waiting phase waiting for unstake completion always appear in the 'net' category and that is the only reason funds would ever appear there. Is this correct or are there other reasons why funds could be in that particular location? I have followed the instructions as per here... https://youtu.be/G6uaBhJvT68?t=136  . Is there a more official source for instructions and information as one seems hard to find. When you say EOSIO cannot give free account to users, is this why there is no undelegate/unstake function within Scatter? Thanks

Comment: Also, are the instructions in the unstake section of the video I referenced correct and include all the steps I need to take? Thank You

Comment: you don't have to wait for 3 day if your staked time exceed 3 days. undelegatebw call delayed transaction action "refund" and if call correctly then you will be refunded. 
After signing the transaction through scatter, make sure your transaction has been executed successfully. you can check it through block explorer.

In your case, something went wrong with your scatter and transaction is not executing properly. Make sure your transaction is executing properly if not then contact scatter team to resolve this issue.

Comment: Not giving free EOSIO free account has nothing to do with scatter not having undelegate/unstake function. Actually, when i last used scatter, it was there. Make sure you're using latest scatter software.

Comment: Yeah that's all you need to unstake EOS. it's probably scatter issue. Again, make sure your transaction execute properly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I shall try again, but do funds transferred to 'net' mean they are supposed to be in the 3 day waiting phase or not? Also, this statement made no sense to me. What do you mean?.... "you don't have to wait for 3 day if your staked time exceed 3 days. undelegatebw call delayed transaction action "refund" and if call correctly then you will be refunded" Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? I'm having the exact same issue. I unstake my EOS, but it never actually becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

When you stake EOS, it is staked to CPU, NET, or both.

When you unstake EOS, it moves from CPU and/or NET to Unstaking.

After 3 days, it moves from Unstaking to Unstaked.

At this point, it should automatically be refunded to your account, but if it isn't you have to manually call the eosio::refund action to move the tokens from Unstaked to Liquid.